# python can not compile to .pyd file

Tags: python

```
cl /LD hellomodule.c /Fe_hellomodule.pyd -IC:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\libs\python35.lib
```

I have run above command in visual studio 2015 command prompt , an error was return:

```
   Creating library _hellomodule.lib and object _hellomodule.exp
hellomodule.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyInt_Check referenced in function _say_hello
hellomodule.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyInt_AsLong referenced in function _say_hello
hellomodule.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_InitModule referenced in function _inithello
_hellomodule.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Any one know how to do , Thanks.